# Code replaced by compiler for Function pointers of member functions

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, function-pointers

It has been really hard for me to understand function pointers call with respect to member functions in the following example.

```
(f.*(FPTR) bp)(0); // This call b()
 (b.*(BPTR) fp)(0); // This call f()
```

I would like to know the code replaced **(as I know a function call like obj.Fun() is replaced by Fun(&obj)** by the compiler for these two function calls when those member functions are virtual and non-virtual. 
Anyone help me to understand, Please ?

I want to understand more like this link explanation: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/8-8-the-hidden-this-pointer/

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Foo
{
public:
    void f(int i = 0)
    {
        cout << "Foo" << endl;

    }
};

class Bar
{
public:
    void b(char c = 'b')
    {
        cout << "Bar" << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    typedef void (Foo::*FPTR) (int);
    typedef void (Bar::*BPTR) (char);

    FPTR fp = &Foo::f;
    BPTR bp = &Bar::b;

    Foo f;
    Bar b;

    /* 
     * we are casting pointer to non-compatible type here 
     * Code works, but want to know how it is.
     */
    (f.*(FPTR) bp)(0);
    (b.*(BPTR) fp)(0);


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: _I would like to know the code generated by the compiler for these two function calls_ And.. You can't compile into assembly, and look for yourself, because...?

Comment: I did not mean assembly code. I was interested in fashion. like obj.Fun() is replaced by Fun(&obj)

Comment: Your invalid cast produce UB.

Comment: It is not giving any error. Above code works fine.

Comment: That's way is UB, not error.

Comment: It doesn't *"work fine"* it's invoking *undefined behavior* meaning the compiler is free to do whatever it wants

Comment: Well according to this article: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c17401/C-Tutorial-PointertoMember-Function.htm#6 The behavior is not undefined. They said,  compiler statically binds it to the pointer. Could you take a look and add more details ? Thanks

Comment: @UnholySheep I understand now. I was confused from the above article I linked. Thanks

Comment: `((Bar*)nullptr)->b()` is also UB. your provided link explain why it (seems to) work in practice in some case.

Comment: "I did not mean assembly code. I was interested in fashion. like obj.Fun() is replaced by Fun(&obj) " Compilers don't actually do that. When people say things like "obj.Fun()" becomes `Fun(&obj)`, what they mean is that the method call compiles to the same assembly as a normal function call with a pointer to the object (which is only true for non-virtual functions by the way). There's no actual source-to-source transformation that replaces one with the other. I mean, there could be - that's up to the compiler, but real-world compilers don't actually work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code displays [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which means that the compiler can do anything it likes, *including what you* (erroneously) *expect* it to do.